# Python pandas returning 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

still learning python, got stuck with this one. My script returned a 'method' object is not subscriptable' error

**Dataframe:** I have 2 columns A & B, with e.g. 100 rows. ColumnA is a set of 1s and 0s. ColumnB is a set of values that can be increasing or decreasing down the rows.

**Condition:**
IF
ColA has a 1 in the past 9 rows AND ColB current row > ColB previous row, then new Cond4 = True
ELSEIF
ColA has a 1 in the past 9 rows AND ColB current row > ColB previous row, then new Cond4 = False
ELSE
just state Cond4 as True.

**Rational:** ColA represents a rare outcome that does not always happen aka always 0. So I need Cond4 to just return TRUE. But if there is an event in ColA(ColA=1), then I need to check that for 9 subsequent row onwards, ColB is more than the previous row's ColB value.

I have two parts of the code I need to build. First is building the df with a "condition checker" which use to run backtests on existing data.

I use the following code and it seems to work.

```
df.loc[(df['ColA'].rolling(27).sum() == 0), 'Cond4'] = True
df.loc[(df['ColA'].rolling(27).sum() >= 1) & (df.ColB > df.ColB.shift(1)), 'Cond4'] = True
df.loc[(df['ColA'].rolling(27).sum() >= 1) & (df.ColB < df.ColB.shift(1)), 'Cond4'] = False
```

Output as per below

[image: Output as per below]

**The second part is where I run into this 'method' object is not subscriptable error.** This second part of the code is supposed to run this condition check in real-time, when new data gets passed to the script.

Following is my function to do this. Cond1 to 3 are my other condition checks.

```
def check_condition_realtime(df):

cond1 = df.alpha[-1] > df.beta[-1]
cond2 = df.charlie[-1] > df.charlie[-2]
cond3 = df.charlie[-1] > df.alpha[-1]
if df.ColA.tail[-27].sum() == 0:
    cond4 = True
elif df.ColA.tail[-27].sum() >= 1 and df.ColB[-1] > candles.ColB[-2]:
    cond4 = True
elif df.ColA.tail[-27].sum() >= 1 and df.ColB[-1] < candles.ColB[-2]:
    cond4 = False
```

Please advise how to correct this!

2nd qns, this 2nd part of the code, those square brackets, are the part of the pandas way of coding? I'm been wondering why I do not have to call a 'df.loc' and the script automatically knows to take the last row of the df.

Comment: pandas dataframe.tail is a method. You cannot use `[]` on it like a list.

Comment: Refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html.

Comment: Use the method as `df.ColA.tail(-27).sum()`

Comment: *facepalm, thanks @JohnStrood